# execute function each time website is loading or var changes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function which should be executed each time website is loading, it's unproblematic indeed but I use framework and every time when my global variable changes the function should be executed as well, but it executes only once. that's the code for reference which works perfect:

```
var buttonClicked = false; //global variable
        function sync(arg, callback){   
        $('.loader').show();
        $.ajax({ 
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'sync/active.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{calling: arg}, 
            success: function(data, status, xhr){
             $('.loader').hide();
             callback(data);

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
       });  
    }
```

and that's the problematic part

```
$( document ).ready(function() { // or if(buttonClicked == true) execute again
sync("patient", function(data) { 
        var res = data; 
        for(var i=0; i<res.length;i++){
            for(var key in res[i]){
                var value = res[i][key];
                switch(key){
                    case "id":
                        res[i][key] = parseInt(value);
                        break;
                    case "kundennr":
                        res[i][key] = parseInt(value);  
                        break;
                    case "client":
                        res[i][key] = value;
                        break;
                    case "start":
                        res[i][key] = new Date(value);
                        break;
                    case "end":
                        res[i][key] = new Date(value);
                        break;
                    case "title":
                        res[i][key] = value;
                        break;
                    case "description":
                        res[i][key] = value;
                        break;

                    case "termart":
                        res[i][key] = parseInt(value);
                        break;

                    case "userId":
                        res[i][key] = parseInt(value);
                        break;

                    default:
                        console.log("error at "+key);
                }
            }
        }
        patient = res;
    });
 }
```

every time I click on specific buttons which may even have different ids but always set the var buttonClicked to true should trigger the function sync which fetches fresh Json data from the server but there is no Or operator in JQuery, does anyone have idea how I could fix this issue?